# Firestore active document snapshot listener breaks sorting

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire, angularfire5

I am running into a firestore issue that I hope someone can help me out with.

I have an active document snapshot listener that seems to be breaking sorting behavior, and I'm not sure why.

In the constructor of my component, I initialize the document snapshot listener once:

```js
this.listen = this.fs.collection('users').doc('0EwcWqMVp9j0PtNXFDyO').ref.onSnapshot(t => {
  console.log(t)
})
```

Whenever I click the Sort button it initializes a new collection query which is sorted by first name.

```js
  async onSort() {
    if (this.first) {
      this.first();
    }

    this.sort = this.sort === 'asc'? 'desc' : 'asc';    
    alert(this.sort)
    let arr = []
    let lastDoc = null
    let queryRef = this.fs.firestore.collection('users').orderBy('firstName', this.sort as any).limit(20);
    this.users$ = this._users$.asObservable()

    // initialize a blank list
    this._users$.next([])

    // subscribe to user list snapshot changes
    const users1: { users: any, last: any } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.first = queryRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc);
        
        const users = doc.docs.map(t => {
          return {
            id: t.id,
            ...t.data() as any
          }
        })
        console.log(users)
        resolve({
          users: users,
          last: doc.docs[doc.docs.length -1]
        })
      });
  
    })
    this._users$.next(this._users$.value.concat(users1.users))

  }
```

However, this is not working as expected. The sort is returning one record (there should be 20 records, based on the limit).

[image]

Interestingly, unsubscribing from the document snapshot, fixes the sorting. 20 records are being returned and the sorting is behaving correctly.

[image]

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Here is a minimal Stackblitz that reproduces the issue.

[Demo of Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xvm5p?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**[Edit]**

Getting closer to a solution and an understanding...
Thanks to @ZackReam for the explanation and both @Robin and @Zack for the the canonical answers.

It seems that `this._firestore.firestore.collection('users').orderBy('firstName', this.sort as any).limit(20).onSnapshot(...)` is indeed emitting twice - once for the active document listener (which has 1 record in the cache), and a second time for the sorted collection (which is not in the cache since `switchMap` will unsubscribe everytime that the `sort` is executed).

We can see that briefly in the functional demo that Zack posted - it flashes with one record corresponding to the document listener, then an instant later, the list is populated with the sorted collection.

The more active listeners you have, the weirder the flashes of results will be.  Is this by design? seems flawed to me...

Intuitively, I would expect `snapshotChanges()` or `valueChanges()` from the `this._firestore.firestore.collection('users').orderBy('firstName', this.sort as any).limit(20)` query to return 20 results (the first 20 when sorted), independent of any other document listeners.  It's counter-intuitive that the first snapshot from this query is the initial active document *from the document query* - which should have nothing to do with the sort query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with your sample data in a simplified environment, and I think I see what's happening.
[Here is my playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-fire-snapshot-playground?file=src/app/app.component.ts), just update `AppModule` to point at your Firebase project.

### What's happening?

When you call `onSort()`, you are making a fresh subscription to `queryRef.onSnapshot`. This callback is firing twice:

1. Immediately on subscribe, it fires with an initial set of data available within Firestore's local cache (in your case it has one record, I'll explain later).
2. Once the actual data is fetched, it fires a second time with the full set of data you were hoping for.

> In the playground, make sure **Document** is subscribed, then subscribe to the **Sorted Collection**. In the console, you'll see both times it fires:
>
> [image]

Unfortunately, *since you are wrapping this listener in a Promise*, you are only ever getting the first fire, and thus only getting the single record that was in the cache.

### Why does unsubscribing from the document snapshot fix it?

It seems that the local cache is populated based on what subscriptions to `onSnapshot` are currently open. So in your case, you have one listener to snapshots of a single record, thus that's the only thing in your cache.

> In the playground, try hitting **Log Cache** with various subscription states.
> For instance, while only `Document Subscribed` is true, the cache only has the one record.
> While both subscriptions are active, you'll see around 20 records in the cache.
>
> *If you unsubscribe from everything and hit **Log Cache**, the cache is empty.*

It turns out that if there is no data to return from the cache in step 1 above, *it skips that step entirely*.

> In the playground, make sure **Document** is UNsubscribed, then subscribe to the **Sorted Collection**. In the console, you'll see it fired only once:
>
> [image]

This happens to actually work with your Promise, since the first and only firing contains the data you were hoping for.

### How to solve this?

[This comment in the `firebase-js-sdk` repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2976#issuecomment-618787294) describes this behavior as expected, and the reasoning why.

The Promise paired with `.onSnapshot` is the major thing that's messing up the data flow, since `.onSnapshot` is expected to fire more than once. You could switch to `.get` instead and it would technically work.

However, as Robin pointed out, focusing on a more reactive RxJS approach taking advantage of the [`@angular/fire` functionality](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#4-querying-collections-in-angularfirestore)) would go a long way.

[Fully-functional example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-fire-snapshot-playground-rxjs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank-you so much! I appreciate the detailed explanation. I'll have a look at your playground and the demos

Comment: So... `this._firestore.firestore.collection('users').orderBy('firstName', this.sort as any).limit(20).onSnapshot(...)`, will emit twice, for each thing in the cache.  This does not make logical sense to me. The query is specific to *sorted users*. Why would it be useful to emit twice - once for the document listener (with one record), and second time for the sorted query (20 records). Why doesn't it emit once with 21 records? I'm not sure how `onSnapshot` is ever useful, if you can't differentiate which query/document that its corresponding to.

Comment: I understand your answer is correct from a "this is how to make it work" perspective. I'm looking for deeper insight as to how we should reason about working with firestore so that we don't fall into these traps. Realistically, practically, and technically speaking, there should be nothing wrong with how I did it initially - it should work as is.

Comment: [Here is an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2976#issuecomment-618787294) in firebase-js-sdk that describes this behavior as expected. QUOTE: "In your case, <DOCUMENT> is the document that best matches the limit() query locally - at least at first. The backend then tells us that there is a different document that actually sorts higher and we raise another snapshot with the server's results."

Comment: So, it's not really emitting "once for the document listener" then a "second time for the sorted query". It's emitting once for running the query against the local cache (for an immediate view of data), then a second time for the query against the backend (since the backend query returned a new view of data).

Comment: My interpretation is that the [realtime update APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), at their core, must be read from continuously. At any given moment, Firestore is giving you as much information as it can, no matter where the data comes from. Thus, never treat a response from this API as "final" because there _is_ no "final"... there can always be updates! Just stay subscribed and keep letting the data flow where you need it, you will _eventually_ have all the data (and continue reacting to future changes).

Comment: Thank-you, for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the problem with your code, because you reached your firebase quota. To me, it seems your sorting is a bit too complex and introduces racing problems. I think you can make it way less complex by using RxJS. Something like this would work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cwthvf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I couldn't really test it because you reached your quota.

Comment: quota will be freed tomorrow

Comment: Thank you for the demo, I'll have a closer look

Comment: This is great example of how to sort correctly. The switchMap will make it convenient to unsubscribe from the listener when the sort criteria changes. Do you have any insight as to why the sort query emits the active document from the cache when there is one active document listener?

Comment: I think it is to get the initial data. It would be inconvenient to wait for the first time the data actually changes.