# In Flutter DataTable Sorting triggers StreamBuilder to fetch data again

Tags: flutter, sorting, google-cloud-firestore, datatable

I have a DataTable where I display some UserData from the Firestore. But when I implement Sorting using OnSort where I have to invoke setState as I have to store the columnIndex and ascending-flag, this triggers a widget rebuild which result in StreamBuilder fetching all the data once more. Also since the List is refilled following the call to StreamBuilder, it undo-es the Sorting as well.

Here are my (relevant) code snippets:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: UserData_StreamPublisher().getUserDataStream(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                usersData = snapshot.data as List<UserData>;
                return DataTable(
                  sortAscending: isAscending,
                  sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                  columns: getColumns(columns),
                  rows: getRows(usersData),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            })
```

```
class _UserData_PageState extends State<UserData_Page> {
  int? sortColumnIndex;
  bool isAscending = false;
  List<UserData> usersData = []; //To be read from Publisher->StreamBuilder
```

```
  void onSort(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
      usersData.sort((user1, user2) =>
          compareString(ascending, user1.counselorName, user2.counselorName));
    } else if (columnIndex == 1) {
      usersData.sort((user1, user2) => compareString(ascending,
          '${user1.dateAndTimeOfCall}', '${user2.dateAndTimeOfCall}'));
    } else if (columnIndex == 2) {
      usersData.sort((user1, user2) =>
          compareString(ascending, user1.enquiryName, user2.enquiryName));
    } else if (columnIndex == 3) {
      usersData.sort((user1, user2) => compareString(
          ascending, '${user1.typeOfEnquiry}', '${user2.typeOfEnquiry}'));
    }

     // This causes the widget tree rebuild ? and consequent call to StreamBuilder ?
    setState(() {
      this.sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      this.isAscending = ascending;
    });
  }
```

I am assuming, onSort does it job and the table is sorted for a small instance. Then the setState in the onSort triggers a rebuild of the widget tree, so the StreamBuilder is invoked again, and it fetches fresh Data and the sorting is undone as the table is displayed afresh with data from UserData.

**Edit**
For now my workaround is to change the StreamBuilder to FutureBuilder (large data, fetch only once) and then to avoid a second call to FireStore due to widget rebuild, I am making a check on the length of the data list.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (usersData.length > 0) {
                 // if usersData already fetched - reload the DataTable  without making a fresh call to Publisher (FireStore)
                  return DataTable(
                    sortAscending: isAscending,
                    sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                    columns: getColumns(columns),
                    rows: getRows(usersData),
                  );
                }
```

Comment: You are using Snapshot() & onSort() so I think you’re having the same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553754/firestore-active-document-snapshot-listener-breaks-sorting) , where they note that Snapshot() is expected to fire more than once and the Fully-functional example seems to avoid this by using switchMap().

Comment: Thanks Priyashree for pointing out the question, but these are 2 different things. The problem there seems to be about cached data and onSnapshot emitting data twice for a single all as far as I can understand. In my case the onSort call (triggered by clicking on the column name of the datatable) triggers a widget rebuild in flutter which results in a re-call to StreamBuilder (or a FutureBuilder - tried that too) and data is fetched again from FireStore (or is it from a local Cache ?!). Either way the datatable gets populated with fresh data and the unsorted data is displayed again.

Comment: Here is a [code example](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-datatable-widget-examples) of flutter using datatable widgets, I see they are using updateSort() method. Hope this helps.